# How can I force Calibre (command-line) to create footnotes in EPUB 3 compatible asides?

Tags: calibre, epub

Currently, Calibre creates hidden pages for documents with footnotes.

ePub 3 and Mobi/AWZ3 support inline footnotes using the aside tag/element.

Is there some CLI command or recipe that I can use to convert documents with footnotes?